# Orchard Supported Browsers and version list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, html, css, orchardcms

I have started developing a theme for Orchard CMS. I want to know browser compatibility issues, because HTML5 and CSS3 are used in this CMS. Does anyone know if IE supports Orchard CMS. If possible, please list out which versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Orchard uses [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) script to enable HTML5 tags in browsers which does not support HTML5. So in this case it renders correctly on all IE versions.

CSS3 is a different thing. It's completely up to the theme designer (so you) to use CSS3 in your theme stylesheets or not. There are some CSS3 features used in Admin theme, but it doesn't affect the usability of admin Dashboard in older browsers. Just some buttons are not as pretty.

**UPDATE:** You could also try using [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) in your theme - it'll add support for majority of CSS3 features in all versions of IE.

Comment: Plus, you're in complete control of 100% of the markup and css in your theme, so it's largely up to you.